# Permissions on Android from Buildozer

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy

I am aware of other topics, but couldn't relate my particular issue with none.

So, the thing is: I wrote a python script that ran flawlessly on my os (I am using a Mac).

But after I have generate an APK (my final goal) I can only save files to APK's directory. Meaning: when I try to save to "/sdcard" either using plyer, or os.eviron, or kivy's tools, I get an error message.

Now, I know I should ask for permissions. And I did. That's why I am kind of lost. I have read and write permissions granted (as seen from the code below).

I appreciate any help.
python code as follows:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
import os
from android.permissions import Permission, request_permissions
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem


class Gerenciador(ScreenManager):
   pass


class Principal(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        request_permissions([Permission.INTERNET,
                             Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                             Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE],
                            lambda x: print('permissão'))

    def criar_arquivo(self):
        try:
            with open(f'{os.environ["EXTERNAL_STORAGE"]}/arquivo.txt', 'x'):
                print('arquivo criado')
            with open(f'{os.environ["EXTERNAL_STORAGE"]}/arquivo.txt','w') as fw:
                fw.write('teste de entrar dados no arquivo')
                fw.close()
                print('arquivo escrito')
            with open(f'{os.environ["EXTERNAL_STORAGE"]}/teste.txt', 'r') as f:
                conteudo = f.read()
                print('arquivo lido')
                self.ids.path_lbl.text = conteudo
        except FileNotFoundError as e:
            print(e)
        # os.rename('teste.txt', f'{os.environ["HOME"]}/teste.txt')
        # os.rename('teste.txt', f'{os.environ["EXTERNAL_STORAGE"]}/Music/teste.txt')
        self.mostrar_caminho()
        return True

    def mostrar_caminho(self, caminhada=next(os.walk(os.environ['EXTERNAL_STORAGE']))):
        print('mostrar clicado')
        caminhada = next(os.walk(os.environ['EXTERNAL_STORAGE']))
        # caminhada = next(os.walk(os.environ['HOME']))[1]

        if caminhada == '\\':

            print(caminhada)

        self.ids.container_list.clear_widgets()

        for e in caminhada[1]:
            print(e)
            self.ids.path_lbl.text = caminhada[0]
            self.ids.container_list.add_widget(
                OneLineListItem(text=str(e), on_release=lambda x: self.mostrar_caminho(os.environ['EXTERNAL_STORAGE'][0]+f'/{x.text}'))
            )


class TesteApp(MDApp):

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        pass

    def build(self):
        sm = Gerenciador()
        sm.add_widget(Principal(name='principal'))
        construtor = Builder.load_file('meuapp.kv')
        return construtor

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = TesteApp()
    app.run()
```

kivy code:

```
Gerenciador:
    Principal:
        name:'principal'

<Principal>:
    FloatLayout:
        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_y:True
            size_hint:0.8,0.4

            MDList:
                id: container_list
                size_hint:1, None


        MDLabel:
            id: path_lbl
            text:'Texto de testes'

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: 'Criar arquivo'
            on_release: root.criar_arquivo()
#            size_hint:0.1,0.1
#            pos_hint:{'x':0.1, 'y':0.03}
```

and for last, my buildozer.spec file:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Teste Storage

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0rc4,kivymd,android.permissions

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 30

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19c

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

# (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
android.allow_backup = True

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.10.0

# (bool) Whether or not to sign the code
ios.codesign.allowed = false

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

For good mesure, here is the logged error:

```
2021-03-15 10:59:09.479 23305-23335/org.test.myapp I/python:    File "/Users/cpeluso/PycharmProjects/testestorage/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 23, in criar_arquivo
2021-03-15 10:59:09.482 23305-23335/org.test.myapp I/python:  PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/sdcard/arquivo.txt'
2021-03-15 10:59:09.482 23305-23335/org.test.myapp I/python: Python for android ended.
```

Comment: https://python-forum.io/thread-27308.html see once here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As odd as it might sound, although  os.environ['EXTERNAL_STORAGE'] refers to '/sdcard' it doesn't work on android.

I had to hard code '/sdcard/emulated/0/Download' in order to make it work.

Hope this might help someone

Answer (score 2):

my solution is:

1. put "android.permissions import" command into if loop，as:

   ```
    from kivy.utils import platform
    if platform == "android":
        from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
        request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
   ```
2. add android in buildozer.spec , "requirement" line as:

   ```
    requirements = python3,kivy, android
   ```
3. compile as :

   ```
    $buildozer android debug
   ```

   buildozer will install android lib autometically
4. Done!

Comment: Which package do I need to install to use  android.permissions?

Comment: it seems that IDEs will freak out about those imports, but you don't actually need to install anything else besides buildozer, kivy and other basic libraries. 

I'm not 100% sure if its kivy, buildozer or android itself that would read it as Kotlin ANDROID permissions. So, even though it might get highlighted, don't sweat. (it might be a pain for testing, though)