# Python Android App Crashes when saving file

Tags: python, kivy

I am struggling trying to get my app to store a text file on an android device. I took some sample code from https://github.com/kivy/plyer/tree/master/examples/storagepath. I installed in and it worked fine on my android device and also on windows. Here is the sample code, I deleted some lines as I am only interested in the 'Documents' path. On pressing a button, the button.text changes to the path to the My Documents file. According to https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage I don't need to request any permissions to do this

```
'''
Storage Path Example.
'''

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Builder.load_string('''
#: import storagepath plyer.storagepath
<StoragePathInterface>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Documents'
            on_press: label.text = str(storagepath.get_documents_dir())
''')

class StoragePathInterface(BoxLayout):
    pass

class StoragePathApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return StoragePathInterface()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    StoragePathApp().run()
```

When I tried to change the code so that it would save a text file, the code still worked on windows and the file was saved but it made the android device crash.All I did was add an Export method to the StoragePathInterface class

```
class StoragePathInterface(BoxLayout):

    ToPrint = ["Hello", "World", "This", "Is", "A", "Kivy", "App"]

    def Export(self, path):
        doc = open(f'{path}/Questions.txt', 'w')
        for word in self.ToPrint:
            doc.write(f"{word}\n")            
        doc.close()
```

And on the builder.load_string I allocated this method to the on_press of the Documents button with the path of the My Documents file as an argument

```
        Button:
            text: 'Documents'
            on_press: label.text = str(storagepath.get_documents_dir()); root.Export(str(storagepath.get_documents_dir()))
```

This saved the text file in windows but not in android, any ideas why it didn't work in android??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer here.. [Permissions on Android from Buildozer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66639629/permissions-on-android-from-buildozer)

added these few lines, didn't need to specify permissions in spec file but with these lines when the app opens, permission is requested and the button works!!

```
from kivy.utils import platform

if platform == "android":

     from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission

     request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
```